# How can i move me in tab / file in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like with a combination of keys to move from one window to another window in the visual studio code editor

For example, I am in the index.html and I want to go to style.css, I would like to change it just by touching some keyboard combination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ctrl + Av Pag and ctrl + Re Pag should do the work.

Comment: If this means `Ctrl+PageUp` or `Ctr;+PageDown` or just `Ctrl+Tab`.

Comment: Yes, its Ctrl + PageUp and Ctrl + PageDown (sorry, I wrote the answer while watching my keyboard). Ctrl + tab works too but in a different manner.